# Javascript adding to an object (used as an array)

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object with the below structure and I'm wondering how to add a line to it.

```
var itemList = {
  '1': { type: "car", make: "audi", price: 500, number: 10, description: "a car" },
  '2': { type: "bus", make: "renault", price: 50, number: 1, description: "a bus" }
};
```

line to add:

```
  '3': { type: "truck", make: "volvo", price: 5, number: 20, description: "a truck" },
```

and I would like to add another line to this array but I have no clue how to even start so any help is welcome!

Comment: That is not an array.

Comment: `itemList['3'] = ...`

Comment: Is the line you want to add an object? A string? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for that I corrected my question and changed array to object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need to *calculate* the next insertion point.

Not sure why you're not using an actual `Array`, but if you have a fixed offset from `0` and a sequential enumeration from there, you can use `Object.keys` to get the number of keys for the next index.

```js
const offset = 1;

var itemList = {
  '1': { type: "car", make: "audi", price: 500, number: 10, description: "a car" },
  '2': { type: "bus", make: "renault", price: 50, number: 1, description: "a bus" }
}; 


itemList[Object.keys(itemList).length + offset] = { type: "truck", make: "volvo", price: 5, number: 20, description: "a truck" }
  
console.log(itemList);
```

But again, this presumes there's some good reason for using this kind of data structure instead of an `Array`.

---

And note that the offset can be pre-calculated if it's not known in advance, again assuming the rest of the keys are sequential integers.

```js
var itemList = {
  '1': { type: "car", make: "audi", price: 500, number: 10, description: "a car" },
  '2': { type: "bus", make: "renault", price: 50, number: 1, description: "a bus" }
}; 

const offset = Math.min(Object.keys(itemList).length, ...Object.keys(itemList));


itemList[Object.keys(itemList).length + offset] = { type: "truck", make: "volvo", price: 5, number: 20, description: "a truck" }
  
console.log(itemList);
```

---

Or if you don't have a sequential set of numeric keys, but need to add one after the current highest key, you can do this:

```js
var itemList = {
  '1': { type: "car", make: "audi", price: 500, number: 10, description: "a car" },
  '2': { type: "bus", make: "renault", price: 50, number: 1, description: "a bus" }
}; 

const next = Math.max(-1, ...Object.keys(itemList)) + 1;


itemList[next] = { type: "truck", make: "volvo", price: 5, number: 20, description: "a truck" }
  
console.log(itemList);
```

Comment: Thanks for that I corrected my question and changed array to object. I'll try this out and see if it work!

Comment: Sounds good. I also added another solution that calculates the offset, just in case the sequence of numbers doesn't start with `1`. Likewise, if the keys are not sequential, you can do something similar to calculate the next index. I'll add that too

Comment: Part of the reason I'm not using an array is probably because i'm a noob but it seem that it's easier / more logical for me to have an object in this case.

Comment: @Slamit: All depends on how it's being used. An Array is just an Object with additional properties/methods, though they're generally intended to be sequential indices starting at `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised none of the other answers have simply suggested switched to an *actual* array (of objects), because then you could simply push a new object into it.

You can then take advantage of all the useful [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) that are available to change/filter your data.

```js
var itemList = [
  { type: "car", make: "audi", price: 500, number: 10, description: "a car" },
  { type: "bus", make: "renault", price: 50, number: 1, description: "a bus" }
];

const newItem = { type: "kite", make: "adobe", price: 10, number: 12, description: "Woo!" }
itemList.push(newItem);

console.log(itemList);
```

Comment: Nobody is giving a *solution* that uses an Array because the OP doesn't have an Array. People can't always choose the format of their data.

Comment: Well, the OP doesn't say that they _can't_ change it either, if you want to be pedantic :)

Comment: lol, don't let the jQuery users know that... they'll start with the *"you should totally use jQuery for that"* comments on C++ questions.

Answer (score 0):

As rmlan says this is not an array, but an object. You could add your new "item" in the following way:

```
itemList['3'] = { type: "truck", make: "volvo", price: 5, number: 20, description: "a truck" };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the index operator like so:

```js
var itemList = {
  '1': { type: "car", make: "audi", price: 500, number: 10, description: "a car" },
  '2': { type: "bus", make: "renault", price: 50, number: 1, description: "a bus" }
};

itemList[3] = { type: "truck", make: "volvo", price: 5, number: 20, description: "a truck" };

console.log(itemList);
```